# CakePHP - Users hasOne Students/ Users hasOne Teachers

Tags: php, cakephp, has-one

I have a table of users, students and teachers. For example I want to create a new student and assign him a user account from the list. This works for me, but it is possible to assign the same user account to more students. How to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: confused!! could you please elaborate a bit what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have table Students with fields first_name, last_name ... user_id what is FK from Users table. For add new student, I have Form on website. Fields are first_name, last_name ... and user.username (displayed instead of user.id) what contains list of usernames from table Users. I assign one user account to Student but it is possible to assign the same user account to other student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add unique index in students table,  user_id field, this  not allow to repeat, the same user_id, in students table.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/create-index.html.

You should use, "UNIQUE".

Comment: Why relation table? Relation table is for M to N relationship. But Users Students is 1 to 1.

Comment: because, you need multiple students for the same account, and users hasMany teachers, or hasMany Students , not hasOne, maybe im not understanding.

Comment: No I need only one student for one account.

Comment: In table Users, there are id, username, password, group_id (FK). In table Students there are id, first_name, last_name,... user_id (FK).

Comment: sry, i was reading bad, in this case, you should keep the same model you have, but add unique index to user_id into students table, this not allow to repeat the same user_id for more students

Comment: Thank you very much. I set unique index in database from phpmyadmin but I want write my own error message when user_id is not unique. Do you know where I must put this in cakephp?

Comment: i guess, now, if you have unique id on this field, cake returns you a exception, you need catch this exception and do something, this can help you  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html or http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/errors.html